# Passing a base64 image string to a Firebase callable cloud function that calls the Cloud Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-functions, base64, buffer, google-cloud-vision, arraybuffer

I'm implementing a web app the uses the Cloud Vision API to detect text on user-generated images.

I'm using React and Firebase cloud functions.

The flow is the following:

- User gets image from Gallery or Camera, crops it using `react-image-crop` package
- This package uses a `<canvas>` element to generate the cropped images
- I'm converting the image to `base64` using `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);`
- I'm passing the `imageBase64` string to a cloud function
- The cloud function needs to read the image and call the Cloud Vision API

**CLIENT CODE**

```
const canvasBase64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

const result = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable("readTextFromImage")({
  image: canvasBase64
});

setTextareaValue(result.data.text);
```

**CLOUD FUNCTION CODE**

```
const Vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const vision = new Vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

async function readTextFromImage(data)  {

  const imgBase64 = data.image;
  const [textDetections] = await vision.textDetection(imgBase64);

  // OTHER THINGS I'VE TRIED HERE
  
  const buffer = new Buffer(imgBase64, 'base64');
  const arraybuffer  = Uint8Array.from(buffer).buffer;
  const [textDetections] = await vision.textDetection(buffer);
  const [textDetections] = await vision.textDetection(arraybuffer);
}
```

**NOTE:**

The `base64` image seems to be generated correctly.

[image]

From Google docs on the Node.js Vision API:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection

We get that:

[image]

When trying with the buffers, I was getting `no image present` and passing the `base64` string I'm getting `code: ENAMETOOLONG`

**QUESTION**

How should I convert the `base64` string into something the the Cloud Vision API will accept?

Comment: whats the value of "const imgBase64 = data.image;"?

Comment: also -->  https://xbuba.com/questions/37824707 maybe useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I've solved it.

I opened a Github issue where I got into more details about this.

https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/issues/808

**CLIENT CODE**

I had to remove the first part of the `base64` string.

This part: `"data:image/jpeg;base64,"`

```
const result = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable("readTextFromImage")({
  image: canvasBase64.split("base64,")[1]  // <--- REMOVES THE FIRST PART OF THE STRING
});
```

**CLOUD FUNCTION CODE***

Also I had to call textDetection with an object with `{ image: { content: base64String } }`

```
const [textDetections] = await vision.textDetection(
  {
    image: {
      content: imgBase64
    }
  }
);
```

Even though **this goes against the documentation** on:

https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection

[image]

But I got the idea from this other piece of doc:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/base64

[image]